# Authenticate a user in a Microsoft Teams tab getContext explanation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm working on a Teams Tab that will access Graph API to retrieve/manipulate data from a list.
I'm having a hard time understanding this piece of code from the documentation provided in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad
The code I'm referring to is:

```
microsoftTeams.getContext(function (context) {
    // Generate random state string and store it, so we can verify it in the callback
    let state = _guid(); // _guid() is a helper function in the sample
    localStorage.setItem("simple.state", state);
    localStorage.removeItem("simple.error");
    // Go to the Azure AD authorization endpoint
    let queryParams = {
        client_id: "YOUR_APP_ID_HERE",
        response_type: "id_token token",
        response_mode: "fragment",
        resource: "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read openid",
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin + "/tab-auth/simple-end",
        nonce: _guid(),
        state: state,
        // The context object is populated by Teams; the loginHint attribute
         // is used as hinting information
        login_hint: context.loginHint,
    };

    let authorizeEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + context.tid + "/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?" + toQueryString(queryParams);
    window.location.assign(authorizeEndpoint);
});
```

I understand that this code will bring the user to the authorization page, what I don't understand is how to modify the queryParams to get what I need for the application.
If anyone can give me an explanation or point me to a comprehensible documentation, I'll be most thankful.

Comment: Actually I've finally found the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc
Will still appreciate any help :)

Comment: Could you please check this sample as [reference](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node) to know more about authentication in Tabs.

Comment: You can learn more details about the `queryParams` from [Implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow). I think you cannot pass your own params here. What params do you want to get?

Comment: Are you still looking for any help with this question?

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity No, I think I have what I need now. Thank you for asking